# Approximate the function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x\rightarrow0$ in a "physics context"

Tags: calculus

So, to reiterate, we need to approximate the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x\rightarrow0$.

This comes from a physics problem (trying to make an approximation in the phonon dispersion relation) and what it really wants, is a Taylor expansion and keep up to 1st order terms.

The problem lies in the following: if your take the Taylor expansion at $x=0$, the linear term goes away and you lose all the physics. My question is if there is a workaround this issue. For example, i thought if we first approximate $x^2$ with $x$ and then do the Taylor expansion, the problem goes away, but that seems so ad-hoc. Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: One of those comments also mentioned that this may be off-topic here and thus appropriate for migration to [math.se]. Our [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) does say that "mathematics in the context of physics" is on topic here, but it could be argued that this doesn't provide enough physical context. I would strongly encourage people who think so to flag the question for migration (or if you have 3k rep, choose the corresponding option in the close vote dialog).

Comment: @DavidZ My comment *was* asking for clarification if the OP meant to say $x\ll1$ rather than $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 9):

The fact that the linear term dissappears is *exactly* what we want. Let's take a brief look at the plot of this approximation

[image: plot]

We see that around $x=0$ the function is flat (the derivative is zero). This observation is encapsulated in the linear term being zero. So this *is* the physics you want. If the linear term in a Taylor expansion is zero this means you are either in a maximum or a minimum and this is used many times in physics (although sometimes in more sophisticated forms).

In general it can happen that one or more terms are zero in a taylor expansion. Especially when the function under consideration is symmetric. In this case the function is even so $f(x)=f(-x)$. You can proof for yourself that every odd power in the expansion must be zero by imposing $\sum_n a_n x^n=\sum_n a_n (-x)^n$

Answer (score 5):

$$
f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}\approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}
$$
for small $x$.  There is no linear term and you can’t “make one appear”.  Your function does not have a linear part near $x=0$.  If you want to have a linear term you need to consider something like

$$
f(x)=\sqrt{1-(x-x_0)^2}\approx 1-\frac{1}{2}(x_0^2-2x_0x)
$$
but that’s not expanding near $x=0$.